# Display executable pages and memory in python

Tags: python, linux, psutil

I am having trouble with 1) show all the executable pages within the processes and 2) have the capability to read the memory.  For the first part, I need to output the address of each executable page and for the second part I as given GDB output as an example of what my output should look like.

Currently, I am using psutil to get a list of running processes, a list of the threads for each process, and a list of loaded modules for each process.

I am really lost on where to begin with these, any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: This is too broad to be a good Stack Overflow question -- we ask that questions be about specific, narrow problems -- but a good place to start might be looking at the content exposed in procfs. `/proc/<pid>/mem`, and Python's `mmap` module, are two items of note.

Comment: ...then again, maybe you should read all of `man 5 proc`. More important to understand the kernel/OS interfaces than to worry about what high-level wrapper to put around them, since you can always build a wrapper if you need one, but you can't create a new interface without writing kernel code.

Comment: Can you put the complete text of your assignment in the question? That way we'll know what we can and cannot suggest. There are several ways to solve your problem - psutils' `memory_maps()`, reading files in `/proc`, using gdb's python api, or using the `ptrace` system call.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, ...I wouldn't describe that as a good SO question, though. Per [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122), a question should be about a *specific problem* with an *existing implementation*; someone who hasn't written an implementation yet isn't ready to ask a question, and "where do I get started?" questions are almost universally too broad.

Comment: Just a first step. Once we see the steps of the assignment, we can ask how far OP has gotten and what specific problem the OP has. If it really is "I don't know where to begin", then it won't be a good fit here and we can recommend OP talk to course personnel. If it's "I have a psutil Process object and need help finding a list of its mapped pages", that may be a good question.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick
Here is the whole assignment instructions:
'Create a program in any programming language of choice that can

Enumerate all the running processes.
List all the running threads within process boundary.
Enumerate all the loaded modules within the processes.
Is able to show all the executable pages within the processes.
Gives us a capability to read the memory.'